# AngularJs: Display HTML elements from string variable in JSP page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp

I'm using AngularJs and I need to render into a JSP page the HTML elements that are into a string variable in the Controller as below:

```
$scope.myVar = "<h1>Title</h1><p>More information <a href="linkhere">Click here</a></p>";
```

So in JSP page I have something like:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    {{myVar}}
</div>
```

But the UI only prints the plain text of the variable. How can I solve this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  AngularJs `ng-bind-html` directive to render HTML.
( [Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) )

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-bind-html="myvar"></div>
```

Comment: Exactly that solves my problem, thanks.